# Find all the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that are orthogonal to the vector $(1,-1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vectors

I was asked to solve the following problem:

Find all the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$  that are orthogonal to the vector $(1,-1)$

My attempt:

I have to find all the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $v•(1,-1)=0$

Now, let $v\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be a vector with coordinates $(a,b)$. Then, $(a,b)•(1,-1)=a-b=0$. This implies that $a=b$.

In conclusion, all the vectors of the form $(a,a)$, with $a\in\mathbb{R}$, are orthogonal to $(1,-1)$.

Is this solution correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Yes.  And correctly concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can also write that as $span{{\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1 \end{pmatrix}}}$